# Web activity chart scraping with R and rvest; overbuff.com

Tags: r, charts, calendar, rvest

The website `overbuff.com` allows to track your gaming history in *Overwatch*, and gives an activity chart. This chart is based on a complicated `html`, which hinders my attempt to collect my data in `R`. Unfortunately, my skills in html, CSS, and web design are at the beginner’s level only.

I give below a minimum reprex, with an example of the currently top-ranked player on overbuff.com.

Website: `https://www.overbuff.com/players/pc/FunnyAstro-2570/activity`

Date: `**2016-06-30**`

When you hover with your mouse over the green circle, the *class="day-popper"* shows the information (win-loss, characters) of this day. But, only after you have done so, the information is available in the source code of the site.
[Illustration: Hover-over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AEsI.png)

With Google Chrome I extracted the XPath, the CSS selector and tried the SelectorGadget. The gadget only selected the green circle without the information.

Here the code in order to get the date (2016-06-30)

```
# Example with the top-ranked player at the moment
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.overbuff.com/players/pc/FunnyAstro-2570/activity"

# Test: Website is correctly received
mydata <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes("h1") %>%
  html_text()
print(mydata)

# Xpath
mydata <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath="/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/section[1]/article/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[27]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]") %>%
  html_text()
print(mydata)
# Null

# CSS Selector
mydata <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath="body > div.container.seemsgood > div.row.layout-content > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > section.activity-date-section > article > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.chart-wrapper > div > div:nth-child(27) > div:nth-child(6) > div.day-popper > div > div > div.sessions-header > div.sessions-date") %>%
  html_text()
print(mydata)
# Error
```

As you can see, I wasn't successful. In order to illustrate the structure of the website, here you find the html snippet for this one day.

```html
<div class="day-popper" data-placement="bottom" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(-91px, 105px, 0px);">
  <div class="ActivitySessionsView">
    <div class="sessions-container">
      <div class="sessions-header">
        <div class="sessions-date">2016-06-30</div>
        <div class="sessions-record"><span class="color-stat-win">17</span><span class="sep">-</span><span class="color-stat-loss">4</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="session-detail mode-competitive">
        <div class="session-header">
          <div class="session-stat session-mode">
            <div class="value">Competitive<span class="small"> S1</span><i class="session-mode-icon fa fa-trophy"></i></div>
            <div class="label">updated at 7:21 AM</div>
          </div>
          <div class="session-stat session-record">
            <div class="value"><span class="color-stat-win">17</span><span class="sep">-</span><span class="color-stat-loss">4</span></div>
            <div class="label">Record</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="session-heroes">
          <div class="session-hero"><img class="image-hero image-hero-lucio image-small" src="/assets/images/heroes/lucio.png?v=8f65c97" alt="Lúcio"><small><span class="color-stat-win">12</span><span class="sep">-</span><span class="color-stat-loss">0</span></small></div>
          <div class="session-hero"><img class="image-hero image-hero-mercy image-small" src="/assets/images/heroes/mercy.png?v=8f65c97" alt="Mercy"><small><span class="color-stat-win">2</span><span class="sep">-</span><span class="color-stat-loss">0</span></small></div>
          <div class="session-hero"><img class="image-hero image-hero-pharah image-small" src="/assets/images/heroes/pharah.png?v=8f65c97" alt="Pharah"><small><span class="color-stat-win">1</span><span class="sep">-</span><span class="color-stat-loss">0</span></small></div>
          <div class="session-hero"><img class="image-hero image-hero-torbjorn image-small" src="/assets/images/heroes/torbjorn.png?v=8f65c97" alt="Torbjörn"><small><span class="color-stat-win">1</span><span class="sep">-</span><span class="color-stat-loss">0</span></small></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract these information for all available days and forge into the following format.

```
library(tibble)
tibble(time=rep("2016-06-30",4), 
       hero=c("Lucio", "Mercy","Phara","Torbjörn"),
       win=c(12,2,1,1),
       loss=c(0,0,0,0)
       )
```

Ouput

```
    # A tibble: 4 x 4
  time       hero       win  loss
  <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 2016-06-30 Lucio      12.    0.
2 2016-06-30 Mercy       2.    0.
3 2016-06-30 Phara       1.    0.
4 2016-06-30 Torbjörn    1.    0.
```

Answer (score 0):

When using CSS selector be mindful of the attributes, so for class you use a dot "." as a prefix , for example

```
mydata <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(".sessions-date") %>%
  html_text()
print(mydata)
```

will definitely get you the date, you can also use "#" for "id".

if there is more than one item with the selector's class, you will get a vector.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Mouad_S. But, unfortunately the session-date class is only available after the user has hovered with the mouse over the date. I have already checked what happens during this action: A GET request is sent to their server, which returns a gzip with the content-type: application/x-bastion-beeps. I am suspecting that this is an custom encrypted file.